# Facebook share dialog custom description

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I have a facebook share button on my website which works nice. However when the user click on the button, facebook dialog window opens and it shows preview of the page content, similar to this:

[image]

The problem in my case is, that the dialog shows actually javascript on the page as description, so I was wondering if that description can be customized to something else instead of page content?

I read somewhere that I should use the following meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mywebsiteurl.com"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Test."/>
```

but instead of getting 'Test', it's still showing javascript code there. Is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: It might be cached. There's a tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ that will allow you to clear the facebook cache an scrape the page again.

Comment: yeah it was cached, that was the problem, thanks.